# show a specific line from a command output Linux script shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed, wc

I want to find the file with the biggest number of words in a directory so I tried to use just the second line from the output of this command :

```
wc * -w | sort -nr
```

In fact I know that it will work if i saved the output to a file and used the command sed like this :

```
wc * -w | sort -nr >> file
sed -n "2p" file
```

but this is not what I want , I need to do it via the output of the command directly

I tried with a script shell like :

```
for i in `wc * -w | sort -nr`
do
if test $i -eq 2 then
echo "$i"
fi
done
```

but it was not what I expected
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about `wc * -w | sort -nr | sed -n '2p'`?

Comment: That is actually working but I'm trying to find out if there is anyway to do it without using  sed command

Comment: try: `... | tail +2 | head -1`

Comment: What tools are you willing to use? *What are you trying to do?*

Comment: I want to write a script shell that shows the name of file with the biggest number of words in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

```sh
find -type f -exec wc -w {} + | sort -nr | awk NR==2
```

- use find instead, wildcard will find folders as well
- pipe to awk